# Hot network questions incorrectly use MathJax

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax, hot-questions-list

This is the converse of http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10570/title-formatting-of-latex-in-stackexchange-hot-questions-list.

I noticed that when on Math.SE, MathJax can screw up the formatting of question titles in the "Hot Network Questions" sidebar that unintentionally use MathJax control characters.

Here is an example:

[image]

Obviously [the question on Webmasters.SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61467/if-icann-only-charges-0-18-per-domain-name-why-am-i-paying-10) is using a `$` sign in the title to talk about money, but MathJax uses it to render in math mode.

Comment: Related post on meta.SE: [Exclude TeX.SE question titles from MathJax parsing in Hot Network Questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229363/exclude-tex-se-question-titles-from-mathjax-parsing-in-hot-network-questions). It wouldn't be hard to extend the userscript workaround described there to apply to all hot network questions (or maybe only those from sites that [don't use MathJax](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216606/which-stack-exchange-sites-use-mathjax)).